# How to find function which return any type

Tags: c#

I have class with methods. For example

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Method1()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int Method2()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public int Method3(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }

}
```

Now I would have function which will find all methods from above class such that are returning int and don't have any parameters.

I think, I can use reflection:

```
    Type type = o.GetType();
    MethodInfo[] m = type.GetMethods();
```

But it give me all methods. So how can I get methods with criteria?

Answer (score 5):

```
var matches =  m.Where(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(int) && mi.GetParameters().Length == 0);
```

Note this return all matching methods in all subtypes. If you want only the methods declared in your type you can use the overload of `GetMethods`:

```
var matches = o.GetType()
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(mi => mi.ReturnType == typeof(int) && mi.GetParameters().Length == 0);
```

Comment: Notice that all int properties with get_ and/or set_ prefixes will be in this set. To filter them you must add in condition `! m.IsSpecialName`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me additionally what are doing these flags?